# Multiple Workstations Path issue - Can I Write/Read to TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, path

I have two applications. The first application writes a text file,
the second one picks it up and parses it...

but I develop on multiple workstations and the file paths to the Source Control folders are different, so I cannot use absolute paths.

**Is it possible to write to the root of the Source Control?** Both solutions are in TFS. I tried using $ as the root, but something was incorrect because my application interpreted my input as "C:\{localpath}\$\". I assume my applications need the permissions to the server, but how would this work, where do I start?

(One answer would be to just combine the first .sln with the second one, but my question could be relevant in other situations, so I will ask it anyway)

Comment: If you have two applications that are dependent on one another, keep them in the same workspace and use relative paths.

Comment: Ok I got it, I was thinking about it incorrectly before